# Java: check to see if a String has 1 or more times in it

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm parsing out text from a file and trying to look at the times. I first need to check if there are times in the text. The only consistent pattern in the text is that all times are denoted as 1 or 2 digits:2 digits. I wrote some java code to see if I could find that the String I'm looking at has one or more times in it.

```
String timePattern = "\\d\\d?:\\d\\d";

if(textWithTime.matches(timePattern)){
System.out.println("MATCH");
} else {
System.out.println("NO MATCH");
}
```

Yet when my String textWithTime equals something like "06:45/07:52/10:27", or "occurred at 06:22" I am told that there is no match. How do I check to see that my text has a time pattern in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matches` checks if entire string is matched by used regex and since only part of this regex can be matched you are getting `false` as result.

Way around would be adding `.*` at start and end of your regex to let it match parts before or after matched substring.

```
textWithTime.matches(".*\\d\\d?:\\d\\d.*");
```

but this solution would have to iterate over all characters of strings to evaluate it.

Better approach would be using `find()` method from `Matcher` class which will stop iterating after first match (or will return `false` in case when no match of regex could be found).

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d\\d?:\\d\\d");
Matcher m = p.matcher(textWithTime);
if (m.find()){
    System.out.println("MATCH");
} else {
    System.out.println("NO MATCH");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To find such a pattern you're best off using a regular expression, something like this:

```
Pattern timePattern = Pattern.compile("[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]");
```

Now you can create a `Matcher` to see whether this `Pattern` is found within a `CharSequence`, like this:

```
Matcher timeMatcher = timePattern.matcher(textWithTime);
while(timeMatcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found time " + timeMatcher.group() + " in the text!";
}
```

Have a look at [the API for java.util.regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html) to see the other methods which `Pattern` and `Matcher` provide. Regular expressions are very powerful.